# Why would the date and time modified in Windows Explorer not match the build date and time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I noticed that the date and time modified for a DLL in Windows Explorer does not match the system date and time.

My steps are:

1. Delete all files from my bin output folder.
2. My Windows 10 system date and time say 29-Sep-2017 11:09 AM.
3. Build the DLL.
4. The DLL Date Modified says 29-Sep-2017 10:00 AM.

Comment: Can you change the source code to be 100% sure it's not copying an older DLL?

Comment: This is actually a GitHub solution at https://github.com/suryapratap/GeographicLib. I have used this on other projects before, but have never noticed if the date modified was off or not.

Comment: Is the dll with the older build date a referenced dll?  Does rebuild solution fix the date?

Comment: The DLL is not a reference DLL.  It is the GeographicLib DLL (main output of the solution).